# Failing to create a file system

Tags: linux, partition, kali-linux, disk

[image][image]I am trying to reinstall kali linux alongside windows 10. I had kali linux, but, yesterday the installation got corrupted. I even had to format that hard drive. So, I am trying to install  it again.

But, during the partitioning phase, I am getting the error - "Failed to create a file system" for swap. I tried removing the swap partition but I am still getting the same error, but, for efi file system. I keep getting something like that.
This happpens for both manual and guided partitioning.

Specifically the error is - "The swap file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (sdb) failed" and the other errors are very similar.

Basically these errors are occurring for every partition like - swap, ESP, and, even the root partition too.

Also, I formatted the hard drive and it's showing Healthy GPT Protective Partition

What do I do now? It's really annoying

*Edit -* I executed `dmesg | grep sd` on the basic ash shell.

And this is the drive that I am using for this installation. I used automatic partitioning for this.

The drive that I want to install to, is `/dev/sdb`

Comment: "_The swap file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (sda) failed_" - do you get a reason?

Comment: Can you show the partition table? Typically the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`. (Insert the output in your question).

Comment: Checking the output of `dmesg -T` after the failure may also be helpful to diagnose what went wrong, in case it's e.g. a hardware fault.

Comment: @roaima it's not giving any reason at all

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer there's only a handful commands available right now. Fdisk is not available, but, dmesg is available and I have added the ss to the question. 
Also I have attached a screenshot of the drive along with it's partitions. That should be enough, I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue on my old computer when trying to install Kali-Linux.
Since I am a newbies I try a few things and I think the last one was the good one.
If you still have the issue you can try directly the last step. But since I am not sure that it will be enough I prefer to give all step I did.\

**1. Boot using Linux Lite Live USB.**

**2. Use gparted to remove old partition.**

**3. Try to install Kali - Linux. It Fail.**

4. Boot using Linux Lite Live USB.
5. Use gparted to create a new partition.
6. Try to install Kali - Linux. It Fail.

**7. Install Linux Lite to get a clean partition properly formatted.**

**8. Try to install Kali - Linux. It succeed.**

Comment: yeah but when I am reinstalling kali, I am getting "failed to create a swap space" during the partitioning process. I am using Guided Partitioning

Comment: If I try to skip the swap partition, I am getting the same error for the efi file system creation